# Angular JS ng-show not working

Tags: angularjs

When I change ng-show binded property from angular JS, still change is not getting reflected in UI. But other property changes are reflecting fine in UI. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="maintainOnlineEquipmentApp" ng-controller="MaintainOnlineEquipmentController">

        <table class="table">
            <tr class="success">
                <td>Equipment Init</td>
                <td>Equipment Number</td>
                <td>L/E</td>
            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="trackLocation in trackLocations">
                <tr ng-click="toggleTrackLocation()">
                    <td>{{trackLocation.locationName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="info" ng-repeat="equipment in trackLocation.trackLocationEquipments" ng-show="{{trackLocation.isVisible}}">
                    <td>{{equipment.equipInitial}}</td>
                    <td>{{equipment.equipNum}}</td>
                    <td>{{equipment.equipStatusCd}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('maintainOnlineEquipmentApp', []);

        app.controller('MaintainOnlineEquipmentController',
            function($scope, $http) {

                this.getTrackLocations = function() {
                    $http.get("/command/maintainOnlineEquipmentAngularPreAction.do")
                        .then(
                            function(response) {
                                $scope.trackLocations = response.data;
                            });
                };

                this.getTrackLocations();

                $scope.toggleTrackLocation = function() {
                    $scope.trackLocations[4].isVisible = true;
                    $scope.trackLocations[4].locationName = 'A';
                    $scope.$apply();
                };

            });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

in the following code ng-show is binded to isVisible property. This property is initially false. So equipments are collapsed. When i click on track location row it should get expanded. In the toggle track location function i am changing the isVisible property to true. Still it is not reflecting in UI. But the other property change locationName is reflecting fine in the UI.

From the back-end when i pass isVisible property as true initially, equipments are expanding properly. Just not working properly through toggleTrackLocation() funciton. What I am missing here ?

Comment: what does `trackLocation.isVisible` give ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) takes an Angular [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), not interpolation tags. Correct notation:

```
ng-show="trackLocation.isVisible"
```